# How to create share url in Box.com Rest Api from Apex

Tags: apex, integration, callout

I want to create share url of a file which is in Box.com using REST API from Apex.

I have written following code

```
public static Map<Integer, boxShareUrlJson> getShareUrl(String accesstoken,string itemid){
         String endpoint = 'https://api.box.com/2.0/files/'+itemid;
         String token =  EncodingUtil.urlEncode(accesstoken,'UTF-8');
         Httprequest request = new Httprequest();
         request.setMethod('PUT');
         request.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+accesstoken); 
         request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
         request.setEndpoint(endPoint);
         String postbody = '{"shared_link":"{"access":"open"}}';
         request.setBody(postbody);
         Http http = new Http();
         System.debug(request+'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~box share request'+request.getBody());
         Httpresponse ApiResponse = http.send(request);
         Jsonparser parser = Json.createParser(ApiResponse.getBody());
         boxShareUrlJson ContentClass = new boxShareUrlJson(parser);
         Map<Integer,boxShareUrlJson> resultMap = new Map<Integer,boxShareUrlJson>();      
         resultMap.put(ApiResponse.getStatusCode(),ContentClass);
         return resultMap;


  }
```

But when I Execute this code I received following error :

```
System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]
```

Please suggest me where I am wrong or missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're properly sending a bad request! Obvious typo: `postbody` holds an invalid JSON, there's an excessive double quote (").

Answer (score 1):

From the official Box [documentation](http://developers.box.com/oauth/), the '400' status code is returned when

> The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported
>   parameter or parameter value, repeats the same parameter, uses more
>   than one method for including an access token, or is otherwise
>   malformed

As endrju pointed above, there's an extra double quote in your POST body. If fixing that still does not resolve the issue, make sure your access token is correct. You can do that by firing a CURL request with same params as in the above code snippet - it's a good way to verify that you are setting all parameters correctly